# Correct usage of the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While doing a textbook exercise I came across this sentence, please correct it, so as to get the correct usage :-
'The teacher gave me many advices.'

Comment: It seems correct. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: We do not offer proofreading services here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly surprisingly, “advice” is an uncountable (mass) noun in English (like “water” or “sand”), and as such it has no plural form:
His advice was very helpful. (correct)
His advices were very helpful. (wrong)

So, a correct form of the sentence could be:

"The teacher gave me advice many times."

"The teacher advised me many times."

https://jakubmarian.com/advice-or-advices-singular-or-plural/